# $n^{th}$ degree polynomial taking integral values at $n+1$ integer points

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-number-theory

Let $P(x)$ be an $n^{th}$ degree real polynomial taking integer values at $n+1$ integer points. Is it true that $P(x)$ is an integer for all integer values ?

Comment: If I am right, it is more often the converse.

Comment: Just to generalize $(0.5x+0.5)^n$ is integer when x is odd and not an integer when x is even

Answer (score 4):

The polynomial $P(x)=\dfrac{x^n}{n}$ takes integer values at all integer points of the form $x=kn$ but not at integer points $x=kn+1$.

If $P$ takes integer values at $n+1$ *consecutive* integer points $a, a+1, \dots$, then it is true that $P$ takes integer values at all integer points.

Indeed, [Newton's interpolation formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton_series#Newton.27s_series) gives
$$
f(n+a) = d_0 \binom{n}{0} + d_1 \binom{n}{1} + d_2 \binom{n}{2} +  d_3 \binom{n}{3} +\cdots
$$
where $d_i$ are the numbers in the first column of the repeated differences array. These $d_i$ (and the entire array) are integers and so $f(n)$ is an integer for all $n$.

Comment: Thanks ! But is consecutive integers a necessary condition, or maybe co-prime will do ?